# Any way to know if another developer is editing the same files?

Tags: wordpress, function, styles, wordpress-theming, overriding

I am working with my teammates on the same WordPress project, but once in a while we face overriding each other's codes, mainly in `functions.php` or `style.css` files. I was wondering if there is any away to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 0):

> once a while we face overriding our codes by each other

When we **fix** or **add** something we may not like to first **ask about 2 minutes
for something that is done in just 5 minutes.** But this gets a problem when multiple persons may work on same file and do not communicate about their work.

> Is there a way to know if someone else is editing same functions

#### You can use any of below ways:

- **Recommended**: use any sub-version control system like **Git** or **SVN**, and work only on your own branch (i.e. create a branch even for a single method/function and merge latter, but you also need to communicate about like: will create a branch and work on ...).
- You could use an **IDE** that has a plugin that adds the feature to **show other developers actions** (e.g. a separate text-cursor with remote-Developer's name above it, like "Google documents").

  > **For example**, VS Code has the so-called "`Live share`" extension:
  > https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share
  >
  > Or, develop a plugin that does add such feature to your IDE, as most IDE's provide `SDK`.
- **Actively use communication** method's in an advanced way (e.g. like working on exactly some file over **LAN**, some software do support that).